# LINQ group by with included table

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want to group by fields in tblInspection and select the most recent InspectionDate in tblInspectionDate, but I don't know how to refer to the field in the Included table.

```
public IEnumerable<InspectionEvent> GetInspectionEvents() //string facilityID)
    {
        using (var context = new FacilityEntities())
        {
            var inspections = context.tblInspection.AsNoTracking().Include("tblInspectionDate");
            List<InspectionEvent> inspectionList =
                (from insp in inspections
                     group insp by new { insp.InspectionID, insp.Inspection, insp.Inspector, insp.FacilityID, insp.InventoryID, insp.Period }  
                     into g
                         select new InspectionEvent
                         {
                             InspectionID = g.Key.InspectionID,
                             InspectionName = g.Key.Inspection,
                             Inspector = g.Key.Inspector,
                             FacilityID = g.Key.FacilityID,
                             InventoryID = g.Key.InventoryID,
                             Period = g.Key.Period,
                             InspectionDate = g.Max(x => x.tblInspectionDate.InspectionDate? something like this?)
                         }).ToList();
            return inspectionList;
        }
    }
```

Here is the tblInspection class:

```
public partial class tblInspection
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblInspection()
    {
        this.tblInspectionDate = new HashSet<tblInspectionDate>();
    }

    public int InspectionID { get; set; }
    public string Inspection { get; set; }
    public string Inspector { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FacilityID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> InventoryID { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblInspectionDate> tblInspectionDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the tblInspectionDate class:

```
public partial class tblInspectionDate
{
    public int InspectionID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime InspectionDate { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual tblInspection tblInspection { get; set; }
    public virtual tblUser tblUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `g.Select(x => x.tblInspectionDate.InspectionDate).Max()` is an alternative, but what is wrong with your sample code?

Comment: What kind of property is `tblInspection.tblInspectionDate`? It would help to see the C# classes.

Comment: 'ICollection<InspectionDate>' does not contain a definition for 'InspectionDate

Comment: I added the classes.

Comment: Should be 'ICollection <tblInspectionDate>'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to group. I think it's safe to assume that `InspectionID` is `Inspection`'s primary key, so a group always contains one `Inspection`, which makes grouping pointless. What you want can relatively simply be queried by:

```cs
from insp in inspections
select new InspectionEvent
{
    InspectionID = insp.InspectionID,
    InspectionName = insp.Inspection,
    Inspector = insp.Inspector,
    FacilityID = insp.FacilityID,
    InventoryID = insp.InventoryID,
    Period = insp.Period,
    InspectionDate = (DateTime?)insp.tblInspectionDate.Max(d => d.InspectionDate)
}
```

The cast to `DateTime?` is to account for inspections without any `tblInspectionDate`.

Side note: remove these tiring `tbl` prefixes from class and property names and use plural names for collections.

Comment: I agree with you about the tbl prefix.  There is a one to many relationship between tblInspection and tblInspectionDate, so I think I need to group by the fields in tblInspection and select the max InspectionDate for each InspectionID.  Every record in tbInspectionDate and a date value in the InspectionDate field.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I've seen so many examples where they did it as I was trying to do it.